# MyFaces and WebSphere Liberty Profile (ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: jsf-2.2, websphere-liberty, myfaces

I've successfully deployed my app on WebSphere Liberty Profile (16.0.0.3), but when I try to use it, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlFormRenderer
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:488)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:271)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:466)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:438)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at pt.sibs.epms.ecc.renderer.HtmlFormRenderer.getRenderer(HtmlFormRenderer.java:54)
```

JSF 2.2 is enabled in server.xml:

```
<feature>jsf-2.2</feature>
```

And the class exists in:

```
wlp/lib/com.ibm.ws.jsf.2.2_1.0.14.jar
```

Regarding API type visibilty, both my shared library and application have `spec,ibm-api,api,third-party`.

If I try to configure another implementation of MyFaces, I start getting `ClassCastException`.

What do I need to change to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jsf-2.2 feature doesn't expose the MyFaces implementation classes as api of any kind which is why the attempt to do a Class.forName isn't working.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Does this mean I can't implement my own renderer?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know enough about JSF to be able to answer that question. I just checked the doc here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_jsf-2.2.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should be able to implement your own Renderers by using a combination of the [RendererWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/render/RendererWrapper.html) and the [RenderKitWrapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/render/RenderKitWrapper.html). These classes allow you to add specialized behavior to existing Renderer and RenderKit instances.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I'll have a look and see if I can make it work, but I'm having the same issue with `org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl` (although I can ditch this one).