# Websphere Liberty ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.MyfacesResponseStateManager

Tags: jsf-2.2, websphere-liberty, myfaces, open-liberty

I am running a JSF 2.2 application in Websphere Liberty 16.0.0.4.

Its using Myfaces 2.2 implementation of JSF, bundled in com.ibm.ws.jsf.2.2_1.0.15.jar . I am getting ClassNotFoundException for org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.MyfacesResponseStateManager .

The same JSF page works fine in WAS 9 Classic, which also uses Myfaces 2.2.

Any help will be most welcome. Please see the stack trace below.

Thanks, Sanjay

```
[9/28/17 14:53:57:669 EDT] 0000002a id= org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils                    
E null java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:88)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
            at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.buildApplicationObject(ClassUtils.java:670)
            at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.buildApplicationObject(ClassUtils.java:542)
            at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configureRenderKits(FacesConfigurator.java:1317)
            at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:607)
            at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:421)
            at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)
            at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:177)
            at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:119)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2420)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp31.java:505)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1064)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6562)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:468)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:463)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:1004)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startModule(WebContainer.java:825)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.ModuleHandlerBase.deployModule(ModuleHandlerBase.java:100)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedModuleInfoImpl.installModule(DeployedModuleInfoImpl.java:50)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModules(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:420)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:406)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.ear.internal.EARApplicationHandlerImpl.install(EARApplicationHandlerImpl.java:84)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction.execute(StartAction.java:141)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.enterState(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1191)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.run(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:804)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize MyFacesFlowResponseStateManager
            at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowRenderKit.initResponseStateManager(FlowRenderKit.java:58)
            at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowRenderKit.<init>(FlowRenderKit.java:43)
            ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.MyfacesResponseStateManager
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:346)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:335)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:310)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:846)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:825)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:477)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:449)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805)
            at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
            at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowRenderKit.initResponseStateManager(FlowRenderKit.java:53)
            ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.MyfacesResponseStateManager
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:499)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:294)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:846)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:825)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:477)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:449)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805)
            ... 43 more

[9/28/17 14:53:57:676 EDT] 0000002a id=         org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer           E An error occured while initializing MyFaces: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.buildApplicationObject(ClassUtils.java:697)
            at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.buildApplicationObject(ClassUtils.java:542)
            at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configureRenderKits(FacesConfigurator.java:1317)
            at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:607)
            at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:421)
            at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)
            at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:177)
            at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:119)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2420)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp31.java:505)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1064)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6562)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:468)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:463)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:1004)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startModule(WebContainer.java:825)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.ModuleHandlerBase.deployModule(ModuleHandlerBase.java:100)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedModuleInfoImpl.installModule(DeployedModuleInfoImpl.java:50)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModules(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:420)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:406)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.ear.internal.EARApplicationHandlerImpl.install(EARApplicationHandlerImpl.java:84)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction.execute(StartAction.java:141)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.enterState(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1191)
            at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.run(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:804)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:88)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
            at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.buildApplicationObject(ClassUtils.java:670)
            ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize MyFacesFlowResponseStateManager
            at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowRenderKit.initResponseStateManager(FlowRenderKit.java:58)
            at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowRenderKit.<init>(FlowRenderKit.java:43)
            ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.MyfacesResponseStateManager
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:346)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:335)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:310)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:846)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:825)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:477)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:449)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805)
            at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
            at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowRenderKit.initResponseStateManager(FlowRenderKit.java:53)
            ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.MyfacesResponseStateManager
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:499)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:294)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:846)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:825)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:477)
            at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:449)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805)
            ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The jsf-2.2 Liberty feature doesn't expose the MyFaces implementation classes, whereas  WebSphere Traditional profile (classic) allows access to those internal classes.  In your scenario the Spring class `org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowRenderKit` is trying to load the internal class `org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.MyfacesResponseStateManager` via `ClassUtils.forName`, which won't work on Liberty and isn't a good practice in general.

If you don't need CDI integration with your application, bundling MyFaces directly - instead of using the Liberty jsf-2.2 feature - should allow this scenario to work.

It may be worthwhile to raise an issue on [Spring's issue tracker](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWF/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel)

Related answer: [MyFaces and WebSphere Liberty Profile (ClassNotFoundException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584059/myfaces-and-websphere-liberty-profile-classnotfoundexception?rq=1)

Comment: Issue raised on spring webflow JIRA tracker  https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWF-1712

Comment: Raised the issue on Spring issue tracker. No movement yet for the past one week.  I opened a ticket with IBM also. They pretty much refused any help, saying that its a Spring bug, For now I have been able to make it work by switching to Mojarra implementation instead of Myfaces in Liberty.

Comment: I used the suggestion made in this article to expose Myfaces classes for Liberty JSF2.2 feature. This hack works great.. https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/680